# nmap: Scantype - not supported

Tags: nmap

When I run the following nmap command to test against my VM's:

```
 nmap --spoof-mac Cisco --data-length 24 -T paranoid -max-hostgroup 1 -max-parallelism 10 -PN -f -D 10.1.20.5,RND:5,ME -v -n -sS -sV-oA /desktop/pentest/nmap/out -p T:1-1024 -random-hosts 192.168.1.183 192.168.1.182
```

I receive `Scantype - not supported`. Any idea the reason why?

Comment: Please read the documentation and understand what all these options are doing. `--spoof-mac` is almost never a good idea; `-T paranoid` will wait 15 seconds between each packet; `-sV` is very noisy and easy to detect, which seems contrary to the rest of the command. etc., etc., etc.

Comment: I know what each command does since I read the doc, but what should I use to tell which commands aren't good? The doc didn't say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your command is missing a space between `-sV` and `-oA`, so Nmap reads it as `-s` with scantypes `V`, `-`, `o`, and `A`.